# Python: isPrime function much slower after adding lookup of pregenerated list?

Tags: python, performance, primes

I am solving Project Euler problems with Python. I have seen some solvers use `isPrime()` functions that simply test whether `x % y == 0` for all y from `2 to x ** 0.5`. That is not efficient and I want to write a better `isPrime()` function, based on the `num % 30` test. This is what I came up with:

```
primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
primality = [1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]

def isPrime(num):
    if not type(num) in (int, long):
        raise ValueError
    if num in primes:
        return True
    elif num < 2:
        return False
    elif num % 30 not in primality:
        return False
    else:
        for prime in primes[3:]:
            if num % prime == 0:
                return False
        seed, sqrt, tryfactor = 1, getIntSquareRoot(num), 1
        while tryfactor < sqrt:
            for trymod in primality:
                tryfactor = seed * 30 + trymod
                if num % tryfactor == 0 and not(num == tryfactor):
                    return False
            seed += 1
        return True
```

Problem 7 is to find the 10001st prime. So I decided to make the code append all these primes to a list which subsequent problems can refer to. I thought that given a 5-digit number `num`, `num in primes` would be a much faster operation that repeated `num % tryfactor`. For parameters where `primes[-1] < num < (primes[-1] ** 0.2)` it should still be faster to get `tryfactor` values from the list than repeatedly generating them through `tryfactor = seed * 30 + trymod`.

So I came up with the following:

```
def problem7():
    count, seed = len(primes), 1
    while True:
        for modulus in primality:
            num = seed * 30 + modulus
            if isPrime(num):
                count += 1
                primes.append(num)
                if count > 10000:
                    return num
        seed += 1

def isPrimeB(num):
    if not type(num) in (int, long):
        raise ValueError
    if num in primes:
        return True
    elif num < 2:
        return False
    elif num % 30 not in primality:
        return False
    else:
        for prime in primes[3:]:
            if num % prime == 0:
                return False
        seed, sqrt, tryfactor = 1, getIntSquareRoot(num), 1
        while tryfactor < sqrt:
            for trymod in primality:
                tryfactor = seed * 30 + trymod
                if num % tryfactor == 0 and not(num == tryfactor):
                    return False
            seed += 1
        return True
```

Of course I expect the code for problem 7 to be much slower, because generating the list of primes a few seconds. I also expect the code for later problems calling `isPrime()` (such as 10, 27, 35, 41 and 58) to run much faster.

However, I got a shock when the code for problems 27, 35, 41 and 58 became much slower. Could someone explain why looking up values in a list is much slower than calculating them? Or is there a mistake in my code? What else can I do to make the `isPrime()` function more efficient?

Comment: My analysis so far is that the list is huge and takes a long time to go through. For very small (less than 3 digits) prime numbers, the `num in primes` operation should find them early in the list and quickly `return True` without going through the whole list. For composite numbers, `num in primes` would go through the whole list, even if the composite number is very small. The list is sorted in ascending order but Python does not take advantage of that. Perhaps what I need is a way to quickly `return False` for small composite numbers.

Comment: If you are curious, look through this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n-in-python?rq=1 that has a number of very efficient ways to find prime numbers.

Comment: @aspie you could use a `set`, using which `in` lookups are `O(1)`

Comment: @aspie Instead of using a list use a set: `primes = set()` and then use `primes.add(...)`. Also forget about this `primes[3:]` - it actually slows down your code, since it recreates the list.

Comment: As a general recommendation, the [line_profiler](http://pythonhosted.org/line_profiler/) library can give you a good idea of which line of your function is the bottleneck ... other profilers tend to stay at the function level.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am not just posting code. This question compares the efficiency of different methods of testing for primeness. Based on the answers, there are data type issues too.

Answer (score 5):

The reason it is slower is because the list lookup is O(n). Instead of using lists use sets:

```
primes = set()
primes.add(num)
```

The `num in primes` check will be now O(1).

Also forget about this "optimization": `primes[3:]`. It actually slows down your code, since it recreates the list (note that it won't work anyway if you switch to sets).

Finally you can implement [the Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) (although there are more sophisticated sieves) to generate primes fast.

Comment: Removing the primes[3:] did make it faster. Thanks! Changing `primes` to a set caused `primes[-1]` to throw a `TypeError` as sets are not ordered or indexed. I thus stored `max(primes)` in a variable and replaced `primes[-1]` with a reference to the variable. After dealing with scope, it worked. Thanks! Can I make the `num in primes` operation quickly `return False` for small composite numbers?

Comment: @aspie It doesn't matter how big `num` is or how big `primes` set is. `num in primes` should always take more or less the same amount of time. And it is fast.

Answer (score 1):

@Freakish answered your question about why `isPrimeB` is slow. Let me propose a couple of alternatives to what you have written.

Here is my version of primality checking with a 2,3,5-wheel, which is the same algorithm as your `isPrime` function but stated rather differently:

```
def isPrime(n):
    d, w, wheel = 2, 0, [1,2,2,4,2,4,2,4,6,2,6]
    while d*d <= n:
        if n%d == 0: return False
        d = d + wheel[w]
        w = 3 if w == 10 else w+1
    return True
```

There are a couple of ways to compute the nth prime. One way uses a Sieve of Eratosthenes. Number theory tells us that the nth prime is always less than *n*(log *n* + log log *n*) with logarithms to base *e*, so you could sieve up to the limit and discard the excess primes. Here's the sieve:

```
def primes(n):
    m = (n-1)//2; b = [True] * m
    i, p, ps = 0, 3, [2]
    while i < m:
        if b[i]:
            ps.append(p)
            for j in range(2*i*i+6*i+3, m, p):
                b[j] = False
        i, p = i+1, p+2
    return ps
```

So, to get the 10001st prime:

```
>>> 10000 * ( log(10000) + log(log(10000)) )
114306.67178344031
>>> (primes(114306))[10000]
104743
```

Another alternative generates candidate primes using a 2,3,5,7-wheel and confirms their primality by a Miller-Rabin test to the three bases 2, 7, 61, which is sufficient for primes less then 2^32 (actually, a little bit bigger):

```
def genPrimes(): # valid to 2^32
    def isPrime(n):
        def isSpsp(n, a):
            d, s = n-1, 0
            while d%2 == 0:
                d /= 2; s += 1
            t = pow(a,d,n)
            if t == 1: return True
            while s > 0:
                if t == n-1: return True
                t = (t*t) % n; s -= 1
            return False
        for p in [2, 7, 61]:
            if n % p == 0: return n == p
            if not isSpsp(n, p): return False
        return True
    w, wheel = 0, [1,2,2,4,2,4,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,\
        6,6,2,6,4,2,6,4,6,8,4,2,4,2,4,8,6,4,6,\
        2,4,6,2,6,6,4,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,2,10,2,10]
    p = 2; yield p
    while True:
        p = p + wheel[w]
        w = 4 if w == 51 else w + 1
        if isPrime(p): yield p
```

Then the nth prime can be computed by the expression `next(itertools.islice(genPrimes(), n, n+1))`:

```
>>> next(itertools.islice(genPrimes(), 10000, 10001))
104743
```

Both methods return the 10001st prime instantly, as soon as you press the enter key.

If your interested in programming with prime numbers (or you just want to solve the prime number problems in Project Euler), you might be interested in [this essay](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays) or in [these entries](http://programmingpraxis.com/contents/themes/#Prime%20Numbers) at my blog.